# Python: Testing equivalence of sets of custom classes when all instances are unique by definition?

Tags: python, class, set

Using Python 2.6, with the set() builtin, not sets.set.

I have defined some custom data abstraction classes, which will be made members of some sets using the builtin set() object.

The classes are already being stored in a separate structure, before being divided up into sets.  All instances of the classes are declared first.  No class instances are created or deleted after the first set is declared.  No two class instances are ever considered to be "equal" to each other.  (Two instances of the class, containing identical data, are considered not the same. A == B is False for all A,B where B is not A.)

Given the above, will there be any reasonable difference between these strategies for testing `set_a == set_b`?:

**Option 1:**  Store integers in the sets that uniquely identify instances of my class.

**Option 2:**  Store instances of my class, and implement `__hash__()` and `__eq__()` to compare id(self) == id(other).  (This may not be necessary? Do default implementations of these functions in `object` just do the same thing but faster?)  Possibly use an instance variable that increments every time a new instance calls `__init__()`. (Not thread safe?)

or,

**Option 3:**  The instances are already stored and looked up in dictionaries keyed by rather long strings.  The strings are what most directly represents what the instances are, and are kept unique.  I thought storing these strings in the sets would be a RAM overhead and/or create a bunch of extra runtime by calling `__eq__()` and `__hash__()`. If this is not the case, I should store the strings directly. (But I think what I've read so far tells me it is the case.)

I'm somewhat new to sets in Python.  I've figured out some of what I need to know already, just want to make sure I'm not overlooking something tricky or drawing a false conclusion somewhere.

Comment: What is the *point* of storing these classes in a set? Sets provide efficient membership testing, but if no two instances are ever equal, then a membership test *always* fails. Why not just add them to a list then? Note that a set is just a dict without a value, so only storing keys. Using a dict instead of a set means you moved the `__hash__` return value to the key and the rest to a value.

Comment: do you think you could include a short example which illustrates this? (children of set seem to compare like set for me...)

Comment: It would of course be silly to store them in one set. I have many objects of type A, and many objects of type B which relate to some but not all of the type A objects.  The point is to determine when two different type B objects relate to the exact same set of type A objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding the question, but this is how Python behaves by default:

```
class Foo(object):
    pass

a = Foo()
b = Foo()
c = Foo()

x = set([a, b])
y = set([a, b])
z = set([a, c])

print x == y # True
print x == z # False
```

> Do default implementations of these functions in object just do the same thing but faster?

Yes. `User-defined classes have __cmp__() and __hash__() methods by default; with them, all objects compare unequal (except with themselves) and x.__hash__() returns id(x).` [docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__)

Comment: I think this confirms it pretty well. Thanks! I suppose it prevents me from ever implementing `__eq__` and `__hash__`, so if I go down that road I can't change my mind and decide later that I want to have objects with equal contents be equal, but I think that's fine.